# Mortgage-Backed Securities

Tags: macroeconomics, stock-market

I was reading about MBS's and according to my understanding, suppose the bank gives me person a loan for house. Then, the bank sells the loan to the investor/government through an agency like Freddie mac in the form of MBS. So, me paying the mortgage money will go to that investor/government, right?

Now, if I default on the mortgage why will the bank take the possession of it? And how do banks and the investor/government profit from my mortgages?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

After the bank sells its loan to Fannie Mae or Freddie Mac, it becomes a mortgage servicer.  The servicer processes payments on the loan, and also acts on behalf of Fannie or Freddie in any foreclosure proceedings resulting from a default by the borrower.  If there is a foreclosure, the loan is purchased at par by Fannie/Freddie  from the end investor (thus protecting them fully).  The bank would send the foreclosure proceeds to Fannie/Freddie.

To answer the second question, the bank makes money by keeping a portion of every mortgage payment for itself, in return for servicing the loan.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Just so I understand :                     Customer -> Bank -> Freddie Mac -> Investor/Government.                                                       Is this the correct procedure of how it works?

Comment: Yes except remove government.   Freddie Mac is a government agency- that’s how government is involved.

Comment: Thank you for your help !!